# Is there anything positive to be learned from biblical examples of polygamy?

Tags: marriage, typology

Is there anything positive to be learned from the examples of polygamy in the Bible? Generally they are treated merely as beacons warning us against that path, but it seems strange to have so many beacons. As well as warning against a danger, do they illustrate anything positive, e.g. Christ's love for Jew and Gentile?

Comment: Do NOT do it!!!

Comment: "the desolate hath many more children than she which hath an husband" (Gal. 4:27). There is more going on here than simply warning against polygamy.

Comment: I agree - that text is NOT about monogamy vs polygamy

Answer (score 3):

I can think of no example where any polygamous marriage produced anything positive.  On the contrary, polygamous marriages produced jealousy, strife and fertility competition.

No wonder that, while the NT never explicitly condemns polygamy, it is banned for deacons and elders in places like 1 Tim 3 - presumably because it would be an unnecessary distraction for church leaders.

Legally, monogamy was inherited by the church and western society from Roman law.

Comment: Yes, I entirely agree with all this but it does not really answer my question.

Comment: @user558840 - then what is your question?

Comment: To take the specific case of Jacob: why did Divine Providence give the twelve tribes four mothers? What are we to learn from that?